# Strange behaviour of the button when calling askopenfilename(tkinter.filedialog) on click

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, filedialog

here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')
def open_file (event):
    filename = askopenfilename()
btn_open = Button(None, text='Open')
btn_open.pack()
btn_open.bind('<Button-1>', open_file)
root.mainloop()
```

after button click and closing open file dialog the button remains 'pushed'. it is still alive and reacts on new clicks, but it remains stuck 'forever'.
what should I change to fix this?

Comment: Does this only happen when the function opens a file dialog, or for any action you bind to it?

Comment: Why don't you use the `command` option of the button instead of binding event?

Comment: command is a good option, thank you! why I used binding? I got it in example I began : )
but the question still actual: what happens if binding used? and one detail more: it seems that a switch to this 'pushed' state comes after call to open_file()

Comment: It seems I still need a 'bind' option because I need to know if an 'Alt' key is down. This information is inside the event I get in bind callback, but no (simple) way to get it when using 'command'